# Is there a buildin/short PHP functions which reverses `array_column`?

Tags: php, arrays

I have for example three `arrays` in one `array`:

```
$foo = [ 
    "id"      => [1, 3, 8],
    "name"    => ['one', 'three', 'eight'],
    "isLarge" => [false, true, true]
];
```

I want simple combine these arrays as exactly the reverse operation to `array_column`, basically I want to obtain:

```
$bar = [[
   "id" => 1,
   "name" => "one",
   "isLarge" => false
], [
   "id" => 3,
   "name" => "three",
   "isLarge" => true
], [
   "id" => 8,
   "name" => "eight",
   "isLarge" => true
]];
```

Thanks in advance!

One solution would be:

```
$bar = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($foo['id']); $i++) 
    $bar[] = [
        "id"      => $foo["id"][$i],
        "name"    => $foo["name"][$i],
        "isLarge" => $foo["isLarge"][$i]
    ];
```

But this seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and solved it, but in a cumbersome way. Should I add that code?

Comment: @ggorlen, adjusted.

Comment: @ggorlen added.

Comment: The answer I added was virtually the same as you've already got and is about the simplest way I can think of doing it.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php, https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php, https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php, and a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid hardcoding the column names by looping over the first row of your array, and then using a combination of `array_combine` and `array_column` to transpose it:

```
$keys = array_keys($foo);

$bar = [];

foreach(array_keys($foo[$keys[0]]) as $columnNumber) {
  $bar[] = array_combine($keys, array_column($foo, $columnNumber));
}
```

This takes each vertical "slice" of your 2d array, and uses each one to create a row in the output.

See https://3v4l.org/nscrh for a demo

On the off-chance that your resulting array doesn't need the column names and all you need is a pure transposition, you can use a much quicker option:

```
$bar = array_map(null, ...array_values($foo));
```

Comment: IMHO this takes OP's simple solution and wraps it in several layers of function calls to just be able to not have to hard code a few column names.

Comment: @NigelRen Absolutely agreed. If there are only going to be three rows in the input then I think hard-coding them is probably a lot clearer, but it depends how extensible it needs to be.